# Dell PowerEdge 1950 Gen II - BCM Fan Speed Issue

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge, ipmitool, fan, bmc

**Please see Update 1 hereunder for an update**

I would like to lower the fan speed of what I consider an optimized in terms of efficiency Dell PowerEdge 1950 Gen II having two quad core Xeon E5335 cpus and 32GB (4x8GB) of RAM running Ubuntu 16.04 lts.

On this server fans are controlled by the BMC

I use `ipmitool` and `lm-sensors` to get the readings

```
user@server:~$ sudo ipmitool sensor | grep Temp
Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | 85.000    | 90.000    | na
Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | 85.000    | 90.000    | na
Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
Temp             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
Ambient Temp     | 19.000     | degrees C  | ok    | na        | 3.000     | 8.000     | 42.000    | 47.000    | na
CPU Temp Interf  | na         | discrete   | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na

user@server:~$ sudo ipmitool sensor | grep FAN
FAN MOD 1A RPM   | 9375.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 1B RPM   | 9225.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 1C RPM   | 6075.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 1D RPM   | 6150.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 2A RPM   | 9675.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 2B RPM   | 9900.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 2C RPM   | 5925.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 2D RPM   | 6225.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 3A RPM   | 10425.000  | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 3B RPM   | 9675.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 3C RPM   | 6450.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 3D RPM   | 6375.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 4A RPM   | 10050.000  | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 4B RPM   | 10800.000  | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 4C RPM   | 6525.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na
FAN MOD 4D RPM   | 6600.000   | RPM        | ok    | na        | 1575.000  | na        | na        | na        | na

user@server:~$ sudo sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +35.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +31.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +31.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:       +30.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +32.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +33.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +33.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:       +34.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

i5k_amb-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Ch. 0 DIMM 0:  +46.0°C  (low  = +105.0°C, high = +120.0°C)
Ch. 1 DIMM 0:  +44.0°C  (low  = +105.0°C, high = +120.0°C)
Ch. 2 DIMM 0:  +46.0°C  (low  = +105.0°C, high = +120.0°C)
Ch. 3 DIMM 0:  +45.0°C  (low  = +105.0°C, high = +120.0°C)
```

Whilst all cores, ram and chassis ambient temperature are optimal, the fans are still spinning fast an average of 8090 RPM and seems like the BMC is not optimizing fan control.

All firmware is updated.

How can I troubleshoot this?

**Update 1**

After much research I have come to notice that most probably the BMC is spinning the cooling fans at a much higher rate as it is not recongnising the brand of the RAM installed Micron MT36HTF1G72FZ-667C1D4.

Had the temporary opportunity to swap the MT36HTF1G72FZ-667C1D4 with another brand and the fans spun down to 3.5k rpm.

Is there firmware for this type of RAM please as I cannot find it on the Dell website.

Comment: Does all component are plugged? like redundant powersupply.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Yes, I am using a Y cable as I am testing power consumption in the same time

Comment: @yagmoth555 I replaced the y cable with the individual power cables, cleared log, but still the FANs are trotting higher that they should be.

Comment: It is very strange that the brand of RAM could cause fan issues. Would you please let me know what kind of fan headers you have on your motherboard? 3 pin or 4pin (PWM). and also the types of fans you have (3 or 4 pin)

Answer (score 1):

Once we had a similar issue. We updated the firmware, but it didn't help. The trouble was in the motherboard battery (CR2032 type). It was discharged, so every reboot it reset all BIOS settings including FAN profile (Acoustic, High Performance) to the default values, so all fans spun at maximum.